# Unable to install MicrosoftWebDriver using DISM,

Tags: selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, dism, microsoft-webdriver

I have tried to install the driver using DISM.exe /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.WebDriver~~~~0.0.1.0. But its failing with below error

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool Version: 10.0.17763.771 Image Version: 10.0.17763.1039 [==========================100.0%==========================] Error: 0x8024002e DISM failed. No operation was performed. For more information, review the log file. The DISM log file can be found at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log

and in the logs as well, it shows below error:

2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM PID=19756 TID=1816 Scratch directory set to 'C:\Users\CNPARMAR\AppData\Local\Temp\'. - CDISMManager::put_ScratchDir 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM PID=19756 TID=1816 DismCore.dll version: 10.0.17763.1 - CDISMManager::FinalConstruct 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM Initialized Panther logging at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM PID=19756 TID=1816 Successfully loaded the ImageSession at "C:\WINDOWS\system32\Dism" - CDISMManager::LoadLocalImageSession 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM Initialized Panther logging at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=19756 TID=1816 Found and Initialized the DISM Logger. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_InitializeLogger 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=19756 TID=1816 Failed to get and initialize the PE Provider. Continuing by assuming that it is not a WinPE image. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnConnect 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=19756 TID=1816 Finished initializing the Provider Map. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnConnect 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM Initialized Panther logging at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM DISM Manager: PID=19756 TID=1816 Successfully created the local image session and provider store. - CDISMManager::CreateLocalImageSession 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM DISM.EXE: 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM DISM.EXE: <----- Starting Dism.exe session -----> 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM DISM.EXE: 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM DISM.EXE: Host machine information: OS Version=10.0.17763, Running architecture=amd64, Number of processors=4 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM DISM.EXE: Dism.exe version: 10.0.17763.1 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM DISM.EXE: Executing command line: DISM.exe /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.WebDriver~~~~0.0.1.0 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=19756 TID=1816 Connecting to the provider located at C:\WINDOWS\system32\Dism\FolderProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM DISM Manager: PID=19756 TID=1816 physical location path: C:\ - CDISMManager::CreateImageSession 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM DISM Manager: PID=19756 TID=1816 Event name for current DISM session is Global{C2003DE0-5D82-4DC7-B7B2-CBAEC2F3E545} - CDISMManager::CheckSessionAndLock 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM DISM Manager: PID=19756 TID=1816 Create session event 0x1ec for current DISM session and event name is Global{C2003DE0-5D82-4DC7-B7B2-CBAEC2F3E545} - CDISMManager::CheckSessionAndLock 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM DISM Manager: PID=19756 TID=1816 Copying DISM from "C:\WINDOWS\System32\Dism" - CDISMManager::CreateImageSessionFromLocation 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM DISM Manager: PID=19756 TID=1816 Successfully loaded the ImageSession at "C:\Users\CNPARMAR\AppData\Local\Temp\050F7FBA-A7F9-441D-AD91-8874F1FF1DF5" - CDISMManager::LoadRemoteImageSession 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM DISM Image Session: PID=21192 TID=19116 Instantiating the Provider Store. - CDISMImageSession::get_ProviderStore 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Initializing a provider store for the IMAGE session type. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnConnect 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\CNPARMAR\AppData\Local\Temp\050F7FBA-A7F9-441D-AD91-8874F1FF1DF5\OSProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM DISM OS Provider: PID=21192 TID=19116 Defaulting SystemPath to C:\ - CDISMOSServiceManager::Final_OnConnect 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM DISM OS Provider: PID=21192 TID=19116 Defaulting Windows folder to C:\Windows - CDISMOSServiceManager::Final_OnConnect 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Attempting to initialize the logger from the Image Session. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnConnect 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\CNPARMAR\AppData\Local\Temp\050F7FBA-A7F9-441D-AD91-8874F1FF1DF5\LogProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM Initialized Panther logging at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Found and Initialized the DISM Logger. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_InitializeLogger 2020-27-0215:42:52, Warning DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Failed to load the provider: C:\Users\CNPARMAR\AppData\Local\Temp\050F7FBA-A7F9-441D-AD91-8874F1FF1DF5\PEProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider(hr:0x8007007e) 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Failed to get and initialize the PE Provider. Continuing by assuming that it is not a WinPE image. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnConnect 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Finished initializing the Provider Map. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnConnect 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM Initialized Panther logging at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM Initialized Panther logging at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM DISM Manager: PID=19756 TID=1816 Image session successfully loaded from the temporary location: C:\Users\CNPARMAR\AppData\Local\Temp\050F7FBA-A7F9-441D-AD91-8874F1FF1DF5 - CDISMManager::CreateImageSession 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM DISM.EXE: Target image information: OS Version=10.0.17763.615, Image architecture=amd64 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM DISM.EXE: Image session version: 10.0.17763.1 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Getting the collection of providers from an image provider store type. - CDISMProviderStore::GetProviderCollection 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\CNPARMAR\AppData\Local\Temp\050F7FBA-A7F9-441D-AD91-8874F1FF1DF5\CbsProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info CSI 00000001 Shim considered [l:123]'\??\C:\WINDOWS\Servicing\amd64_microsoft-windows-servicingstack_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17763.1_none_fa254b2e1f73e660\wcp.dll' : got STATUS_OBJECT_PATH_NOT_FOUND 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info CSI 00000002 Shim considered [l:120]'\??\C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-servicingstack_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17763.1_none_fa254b2e1f73e660\wcp.dll' : got STATUS_SUCCESS 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM DISM Package Manager: PID=21192 TID=19116 Finished initializing the CbsConUI Handler. - CCbsConUIHandler::Initialize 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info CSI 00000001 Shim considered [l:123]'\??\C:\WINDOWS\Servicing\amd64_microsoft-windows-servicingstack_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17763.1_none_fa254b2e1f73e660\wcp.dll' : got STATUS_OBJECT_PATH_NOT_FOUND 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info CSI 00000002 Shim considered [l:120]'\??\C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-servicingstack_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17763.1_none_fa254b2e1f73e660\wcp.dll' : got STATUS_SUCCESS 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM DISM Package Manager: PID=21192 TID=19116 CBS is being initialized for online use. More information about CBS actions can be located at: %windir%\logs\cbs\cbs.log - CDISMPackageManager::Initialize 2020-27-0215:42:52, Info DISM DISM Package Manager: PID=21192 TID=19116 Loaded servicing stack for online use only. - CDISMPackageManager::CreateCbsSession 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\CNPARMAR\AppData\Local\Temp\050F7FBA-A7F9-441D-AD91-8874F1FF1DF5\MsiProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\CNPARMAR\AppData\Local\Temp\050F7FBA-A7F9-441D-AD91-8874F1FF1DF5\IntlProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\CNPARMAR\AppData\Local\Temp\050F7FBA-A7F9-441D-AD91-8874F1FF1DF5\IBSProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\CNPARMAR\AppData\Local\Temp\050F7FBA-A7F9-441D-AD91-8874F1FF1DF5\DmiProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info CSI 00000001 Shim considered [l:123]'\??\C:\WINDOWS\Servicing\amd64_microsoft-windows-servicingstack_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17763.1_none_fa254b2e1f73e660\wcp.dll' : got STATUS_OBJECT_PATH_NOT_FOUND 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info CSI 00000002 Shim considered [l:120]'\??\C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-servicingstack_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17763.1_none_fa254b2e1f73e660\wcp.dll' : got STATUS_SUCCESS 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM Driver Manager: PID=21192 TID=19116 Further logs for driver related operations can be found in the target operating system at %WINDIR%\inf\setupapi.offline.log - CDriverManager::Initialize 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\CNPARMAR\AppData\Local\Temp\050F7FBA-A7F9-441D-AD91-8874F1FF1DF5\UnattendProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\CNPARMAR\AppData\Local\Temp\050F7FBA-A7F9-441D-AD91-8874F1FF1DF5\SmiProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider 2020-27-0215:42:53, Warning DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Failed to load the provider: C:\Users\CNPARMAR\AppData\Local\Temp\050F7FBA-A7F9-441D-AD91-8874F1FF1DF5\EmbeddedProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider(hr:0x8007007e) 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\CNPARMAR\AppData\Local\Temp\050F7FBA-A7F9-441D-AD91-8874F1FF1DF5\AppxProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\CNPARMAR\AppData\Local\Temp\050F7FBA-A7F9-441D-AD91-8874F1FF1DF5\ProvProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\CNPARMAR\AppData\Local\Temp\050F7FBA-A7F9-441D-AD91-8874F1FF1DF5\AssocProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\CNPARMAR\AppData\Local\Temp\050F7FBA-A7F9-441D-AD91-8874F1FF1DF5\GenericProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\CNPARMAR\AppData\Local\Temp\050F7FBA-A7F9-441D-AD91-8874F1FF1DF5\OfflineSetupProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\CNPARMAR\AppData\Local\Temp\050F7FBA-A7F9-441D-AD91-8874F1FF1DF5\SysprepProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\CNPARMAR\AppData\Local\Temp\050F7FBA-A7F9-441D-AD91-8874F1FF1DF5\TransmogProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM Transmog Provider: PID=21192 TID=19116 Current image session is [ONLINE] - CTransmogManager::GetMode 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM Transmog Provider: PID=21192 TID=19116 Audit Mode: [No] - CTransmogManager::Initialize 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM Transmog Provider: PID=21192 TID=19116 GetProductType: ProductType = [WinNT] - CTransmogManager::GetProductType 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM Transmog Provider: PID=21192 TID=19116 Product Type: [WinNT] - CTransmogManager::Initialize 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM Transmog Provider: PID=21192 TID=19116 Product Type ServerNT : [No] - CTransmogManager::Initialize 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\CNPARMAR\AppData\Local\Temp\050F7FBA-A7F9-441D-AD91-8874F1FF1DF5\SetupPlatformProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM.EXE: Got the collection of providers. Now enumerating them to build the command table. 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: DISM Log Provider 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: OSServices 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: DISM Package Manager 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: DISM Package Manager. 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: MsiManager 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: MsiManager. 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: IntlManager 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: IntlManager. 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: IBSManager 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: DriverManager 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: DriverManager. 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: DISM Unattend Manager 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: DISM Unattend Manager. 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: SmiManager 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: AppxManager 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: AppxManager. 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: ProvManager 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: ProvManager. 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: AssocManager 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: AssocManager. 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: GenericManager 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: GenericManager. 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: OfflineSetupManager 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: OfflineSetupManager. 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: SysprepManager 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: SysprepManager. 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: Edition Manager 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: Edition Manager. 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: SetupPlatformManager 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: SetupPlatformManager. 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM Package Manager: PID=21192 TID=19116 Processing the top level command token(add-capability). - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_ValidateCmdLine 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM Package Manager: PID=21192 TID=19116 Attempting to route to appropriate command handler. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM Package Manager: PID=21192 TID=19116 Routing the command... - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine 2020-27-0215:42:53, Info DISM DISM Package Manager: PID=21192 TID=19116 CBS session options=0x40100! - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM Package Manager: PID=21192 TID=22576 Error in operation: (null) (CBS HRESULT=0x8024002e) - CCbsConUIHandler::Error 2020-27-0215:42:57, Error DISM DISM Package Manager: PID=21192 TID=19116 Failed finalizing changes. - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize(hr:0x8024002e) 2020-27-0215:42:57, Error DISM DISM Package Manager: PID=21192 TID=19116 Failed processing package changes with session options - CDISMPackageManager::ProcessChangesWithOptions(hr:0x8024002e) 2020-27-0215:42:57, Error DISM DISM Package Manager: PID=21192 TID=19116 Failed to install capability. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ProcessCmdLine_AddCapability(hr:0x8024002e) 2020-27-0215:42:57, Error DISM DISM Package Manager: PID=21192 TID=19116 Failed while processing command add-capability. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine(hr:0x8024002e) 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM Package Manager: PID=21192 TID=19116 Further logs for online package and feature related operations can be found at %WINDIR%\logs\CBS\cbs.log - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine 2020-27-0215:42:57, Error DISM DISM.EXE: DISM Package Manager processed the command line but failed. HRESULT=8024002E 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Found the OSServices. Waiting to finalize it until all other providers are unloaded. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnDisconnect 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Found the OSServices. Waiting to finalize it until all other providers are unloaded. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnDisconnect 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Found the PE Provider. Waiting to finalize it until all other providers are unloaded. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnDisconnect 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Finalizing the servicing provider(DISM Package Manager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM Package Manager: PID=21192 TID=19116 Finalizing CBS core. - CDISMPackageManager::Finalize 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Disconnecting Provider: DISM Package Manager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Finalizing the servicing provider(MsiManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Disconnecting Provider: MsiManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Finalizing the servicing provider(IntlManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Disconnecting Provider: IntlManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Finalizing the servicing provider(IBSManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Disconnecting Provider: IBSManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Finalizing the servicing provider(DriverManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Disconnecting Provider: DriverManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Finalizing the servicing provider(DISM Unattend Manager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Disconnecting Provider: DISM Unattend Manager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Finalizing the servicing provider(SmiManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Disconnecting Provider: SmiManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Finalizing the servicing provider(AppxManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Disconnecting Provider: AppxManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Finalizing the servicing provider(ProvManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Disconnecting Provider: ProvManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Finalizing the servicing provider(AssocManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Disconnecting Provider: AssocManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Finalizing the servicing provider(GenericManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Disconnecting Provider: GenericManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Finalizing the servicing provider(OfflineSetupManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Disconnecting Provider: OfflineSetupManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Finalizing the servicing provider(SysprepManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Disconnecting Provider: SysprepManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Finalizing the servicing provider(Edition Manager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Disconnecting Provider: Edition Manager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Finalizing the servicing provider(SetupPlatformManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Disconnecting Provider: SetupPlatformManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Releasing the local reference to OSServices. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Disconnecting Provider: OSServices - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM Provider Store: PID=21192 TID=19116 Releasing the local reference to DISMLogger. Stop logging. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM Manager: PID=19756 TID=1816 Closing session event handle 0x1ec - CDISMManager::CleanupImageSessionEntry 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM.EXE: Image session has been closed. Reboot required=no. 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM.EXE: 2020-27-0215:42:57, Info DISM DISM.EXE: <----- Ending Dism.exe session ----->

Comment: Associated questions doesn't answer mine. I would like to know the answer for the issue with DISM while installing Microsoft webdriver.

Comment: Is the Developer mode is enabled? Please check whether you are allowed to install any application on the machine, many times some security policies are applied which prevents the user to install apps. If any other machine is available then try to install the web driver on that machine to check whether this is a machine-specific issue or not.

Comment: Yes.developer mode is enabled. As you said, this particular issue occures in my remote machine only. Might be an access issue. Anyway I have raised a ticket for this. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Thanks for updating us with the current status of this issue. If you get a solution then you can share here in the comments. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.